# how to convert a list of text to a data frame in R

Tags: r, string

I have a csv file which is a little jumbled up, say:

```
- Page 1
- Hugh
- Grant
- First Name:
- Last Name:
- Age: 54
- Movies:
- Notting Hill
- 4 Weddings & A Funeral
- Music and Lyrics
- Scarlett
- Johansson
- First Name:
- Last Name:
- Age: 29
- Movies:
- The Avengers
- Chef
- Lucy
- Page 2
- Mark
- Wahlberg
- First Name:
- Last Name:
- Age: 43
- Movies:
- Ted
- Transformers: Age of Extinction
```

I want to make this into a table like the following:

```
- First Name Last Name Age Movies
- Hugh       Grant     54  Notting Hill, 4 Weddings & a Funeral, Music & Lyric
- Scarlett   Johansson 29  The Avengers, Chef, Lucy
- Mark       Wahlberg  43  Ted, Transformers: Age of Extinction
```

How do I go about creating such a data frame in R? Note that the original list is about 16000 long (i.e. 16000 by 1 dataframe).

Comment: A "little" jumbled up? You say this is a CSV file, but your input shows no delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data showed, you may try

```
 lines <- readLines("movies.txt")
 lines1 <- lines[!grepl("Page", lines)]
 indx <- grep("(First|Last|Age|Movies).*:$", lines1)
 indx1 <- grep("First.*:", lines1)
 indx2 <- grep("Movies:", lines1)

 m1 <- t(sapply(c(-1,-2, 3), function(i) lines1[indx1+i]))[c(2,1,3),]
 m2 <-  t(sapply(1:3, function(i) lines1[indx2+i]))
 m3 <- rbind(m1, m2)
 library(stringr)
 dat <- data.frame(names= c(unique(lines1[indx]),rep('-', 2)),
        matrix(str_trim(gsub("-","",  m3)), nrow=6), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 dat
 #         names                     X1           X2
 #1 - First Name:                   Hugh     Scarlett
 #2  - Last Name:                  Grant    Johansson
 #3        - Age:                     54           29
 #4     - Movies:           Notting Hill The Avengers
 #5             - 4 Weddings & A Funeral         Chef
 #6             -       Music and Lyrics         Lucy
  #                              X3
 #1                            Mark
 #2                        Wahlberg
 #3                              43
 #4                             Ted
 #5 Transformers: Age of Extinction
 #6                            <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks! Great help here!